# How to create an iOS style dragging using HammerJS and CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hammer.js

I'm trying to create an iOS 'style' modal sheet that that will popup and then the users can drag it down and the modal sheet will follow the users touch gesture and then it will disappear OFF the screen using HammerJS.

I've managed to create the modal sheet and I have also implemented the HammerJS to a certain extend.

When the user 'swipes' down the modal sheet, it will disappear but it doesn't follow the swipe/touch gesture before it hides. it just disappears which makes it a bit clunky.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.button', function() {
  $('.addreFinder').css('bottom', '0');
  $('.sheet-backdrop').addClass('backdrop-in');
});

///custom modal sheet///
$('.c-modal').each(function() {
  var mc = new Hammer(this);

  mc.get('swipe').set({
    direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL
  });

  mc.on("swipedown", function(ev) {
    console.log('dragged');
    $('.modal-in').css('bottom', '-1850px');
    $('.sheet-backdrop').removeClass('backdrop-in');
  });
});
```

```css
.sheet-modal.modal-in {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1850px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: bottom 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  display: block;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 13200;
}

.sheet-modal.modal-in,
.sheet-modal.modal-out {
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.demo-sheet-swipe-to-close,
.demo-sheet-swipe-to-step {
  --f7-sheet-bg-color: #fff;
  --f7-sheet-border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sheet-modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition-property: transform;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  background: var(--f7-sheet-bg-color);
  z-index: 12500;
  will-change: transform;
}

.swipe-handler {
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
}

.page-content {
  will-change: scroll-position;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: calc(var(--f7-page-navbar-offset, 0px) + var(--f7-page-toolbar-top-offset, 0px) + var(--f7-page-subnavbar-offset, 0px) + var(--f7-page-searchbar-offset, 0px) + var(--f7-page-content-extra-padding-top, 0px));
  padding-bottom: calc(var(--f7-page-toolbar-bottom-offset, 0px) + var(--f7-safe-area-bottom) + var(--f7-page-content-extra-padding-bottom, 0px));
}

.swipe-handler:after {
  content: '';
  width: 36px;
  height: 6px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -18px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #666;
}

.block-title-large {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.block {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sheet-backdrop.backdrop-in {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.sheet-backdrop {
  z-index: 11000;
}

.actions-backdrop,
.custom-modal-backdrop,
.dialog-backdrop,
.popover-backdrop,
.popup-backdrop,
.preloader-backdrop,
.sheet-backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  z-index: 13000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-duration: .4s;
}

.bbody {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;
  font-size: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.search {
  padding: 0 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submit {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') no-repeat center center, #1e1e20;
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 80px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.pac-container {
  width: 100%;
}

.pac-item {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 4px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  color: #999;
  width: 100%;
}

.pac-icon {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-image: url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/autocomplete-icons.png);
  background-size: 34px;
}

.pac-icon-marker {
  background-position: -1px -161px;
}

.addressFinderTexts>* {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.addressFinderTexts p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.useMyCureentLOcationBtn {
  width: 80%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ffaf06;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.addressFinderTexts {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 380px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.js"></script>
<div class="sheet-backdrop"></div>
<div class="c-modal sheet-modal demo-sheet-swipe-to-close modal-in addreFinder" id="addressFinder">
  <div class="sheet-modal-inner">
    <div class="swipe-handler"></div>
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="bbody">
          Drag me down to hide me
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="button">Click Here To show modal</button>
```

I hope I have explained the situation properly for someone to be able to help me.

Comment: is this problem solved. Please update the answer if you found solution.